# Retag request: Should duplicate-files be aliased to deduplication?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

In tagging a question I noticed [duplicate-files](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-files) (24) and [deduplication](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/deduplication) (38).

The tag wiki for the latter seemed like the right thing for my question, but most of the questions filed under duplicate-files seem like deduplication questions.  Should they be aliased?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me duplication should be killed and rolled into duplicate files. Duplication sounds like it could refer to good things and is ambiguous.

Examples of alternate uses for duplications:

- Drive Duplication
- Copy Files
- Duplicates of Files
- Exact Duplicates (A current tag)

I would rather more explicit tags for these, I am newer and still mastering the site but this makes the most sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with duplicate files and deduplication are really 2 different sciences, especially if you drag ZFS (or similar) dedup into the conversation.

I think that for things that deal with duplicate files, and how to link/remove them, they should be tagged as [duplicate-files](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-files).

For other things like ZFS dedup, and other similar technologies, [deduplication](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/deduplication) would be right.

But, I could be wrong.